# How to allow only a certain set of domains in javascript and throw an alert if its not matchin?

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to validate if the url entered in the textbox is a valid domain by comparing it with a set of valid domains and return an alert if its not matching. Can you please help me with this ?

The URL should be of the format http://www.*.abc.com/cdef.. http://www.*.xyz.com etc..

I have tried using this regex:

```
regex = /((http|https):\/\/)(www.)?([a-zA-Z0-9]+).((abc.com)|(xyz.com)).*/
```

but its not yielding proper results. Hope this info helps.

Comment: What have you tried? It depends on your domains, how the regex would look like! Why do the validation on the client? Why with regex? Please add more context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using JavaScript [**`URL`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) object and its `host` property:

```
function isAllowed(urlString)
{
    var allowed = ['example.com', 'stackoverflow.com', 'google.com'];
    var urlObject = new URL(urlString);

    return allowed.indexOf(urlObject.host) > -1;
}

console.log(isAllowed('http://example.com/path/?q=1')); // true
console.log(isAllowed('https://subdomain.example.com/')); // false
console.log(isAllowed('http://stacksnippets.net')); // false

if (!isAllowed(document.getElementById('yourTextbox').value))
{
    alert('Domain is not allowed!');
}
```

Note that it may not work in all browsers.
Check the compatibility table in the given reference.

Comment: for older browsers, I think I remember that anchor elements had this `host` property too, so `var a = document.createElement('a'); a.href=urlString; return a.host;` should be a possible fallback if URL is not supported. Not sure though.

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic programming exercise. 
You can use a put your urls in an array and then loop through them to check against what you entered.

Here's a jsfiddle of something I hack together quickly. Learn to write it yourself afterwards and you can hack together small programs to help you do mundane tasks.

```
var listOfUrl = [
 'www.yahoo.com', 
 'www.google.com',
 'www.bing.com'
 //enter more url here...
 ];


 for(var i = 0; i <= listOfUrl.length; i++) {
   if(listOfUrl[i] === enteredUrl){
   document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'there is a match';
   return;
 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/henryw4k/5mogf06t/